# error: undeclared here (not in a function)

Tags: c, file-io, struct

I am getting this error on the last line of the code, as I am trying to read data from an extra.txt file. Records are read properly from an input.txt but not sure why it is throwing error for extra file. Thanks!

```
typedef struct {
    char* fname;
    char* lname;
    int id;
    int age;
} data;

typedef struct {
    data** array;
    int len;
    int cap;
}vector;

vector* vector_read(FILE* in_file)
{
    int i;
    vector *v = (vector*)malloc(sizeof(vector));
    fscanf(in_file,"%d",&v->len);
    if(in_file=NULL)
     {
       return NULL;
     }
    printf("%d",v->len);
    data** array = (data**)malloc(sizeof(data*)*(v->len));
    v->array = array;
    data *temp;

   for(i=0;i<(v->len);i++)
   {    
     temp = data_read(in_file);        
     v->array[i] = temp;
   }

return v;
}

    vector *v = vector_read(input);
    printf( "initial state of vector v\n");
    vector_print(v);
    vector *v_add = vector_read(extra);
```

EDIT:

extra.txt has records in this fashion:

```
4

Barak Obama 101 50  
Joe Biden 102 55  
Joe Plumber 10293 45  
Wayne Gretzky 99 56
```

and input.txt

```
1

Aaaa
Aooo
1
20
```

Comment: You need to provide more of the code. What do your definitions of `input` and `extra` look like?

Comment: @vp881: Not the content of the files, but you would have done `FILE* input;` somewhere in your code. Have you done `FILE* extra` also or not?

Comment: @JoakimGebart Added the format for input and extra

Comment: @Naveen yes i did FILE* extra

Comment: And also, the lines starting from `vector *v = vector_read(input);` should be inside some function (for example `main`). Can you post the code you are trying to compile directly copy pasting from your editor?

Comment: Can you post your entire main() function? (or whatever function the last four lines of code are taken from)

Comment: Thanks, I Got the answer.. I received Segmentation fault too. then used Valgrind.. As I was setting in_file=NULL instead of in_file==NULL.
So Silly uhhhh Sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs go inside a function.

For example like this:

```
int read_input_and_extra(FILE * input, FILE * extra)
{
  vector *v = vector_read(input);
  if (!v)
    return -1;

  printf( "initial state of vector v\n");
  vector_print(v);

  vector *v_add = vector_read(extra); 
  if (!v_add)
    return -2;

  return 0;
}
```